# How to put P-Values and R-squared into a SAS data set at the same time?

Tags: sas, regression

I'm running this code in SAS:

```
%let control = A;
%let test = B C D E F;

ods output ParameterEstimates = parms;

proc reg data=reg_data outest=work.model tableout;
    model &control = &test / selection= rsquare adjrsq;
run;

proc sql;
  create table max_r_square as
  select *
  from work.model
  order by _ADJRSQ_ desc, _RSQ_ desc;
quit;
```

It effectively goes through all of the combinations of the `test` variable and then drops the information including R-Squared into a data set.  From there I can choose the model that has the highest R-Squared.

My problem is, I can't find a way for the table to include R-Squared and P-Values at the same time while going through all combinations of the `test` variable.

Taking out the `rsquare` and `adjrsq` options gets the p-values in a table, but it keeps SAS from running code on all of the combinations.

I've been looking through the `proc reg` arguments and options and haven't found anything that works so far.

Is there a way to have SAS run a regression on all combinations of input variables and output R-Squared and P-Values into the same table?

Comment: No, they don't go into a single table by default, but you can post process the results and put them together.

Comment: @Reeza, thank you for the answer.  Do you know of a way to get `Proc Reg` to go through all combinations of regressors and put the P-Value into a table? Once I figure that out I can put the results together.  But I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: You're asking two questions, one is how to get the results into a table and one to run all possible regressions. Figure out how to get the information you want first, then generalize it to all possible models. There's an example here that shows how to run all possible regressions: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Run-regressions-with-combinations-of-multiple-variables/m-p/228277/highlight/true#M54262

Comment: and note the comments - this is technically possible but statistically invalid - p-value fishing at best.

Comment: @Reeza Thank you for the link and the points you made.  I think I'll have to back up a little bit and reassess what all I'm doing.  Thank you.